# Bind "mousedown" on PhoneJS

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, phonejs

I'm trying to build a list of "posts" (facebook like) where an user can click on them to collapse them.
I'm using this code to perform this task:

```
$("body").on( "mousedown", ".feeds > li", function() {

    $(this).addClass("active");

} );
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work.
If I replace `.feeds > li` with `*` and I add an alert to the function:

```
$("body").on( "mousedown", "*", function() {

    alert("mousedown");

} );
```

The event is fired only if I click on the **SlideOut menu**, if I click on the rest of the page it is not fired.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar issue was discussed [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q535734)